# Как правильно создавать параллельные потоки?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня задание:
Необходимо создать два Thread. Первый будет считать количество слов. Второй количество пробелов в тексте.

Вывести результат на экран.

Продемонстрировать, что программа выполняется параллельно. Это должно быть видно по выводу.

Я делаю это так:

```
public class CounterOfSpace {
    private int counterOfSpaces;
    private int counterOfWords;
    private String text;

    public CounterOfSpace(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    void calcSpaces() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                    if (c == ' ') {
                        counterOfSpaces++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfSpaces "+counterOfSpaces);
                    }
                }
                                }
        }).start();
    }

    void calcWords() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                String[] words = text.split(" ");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (!word.equals(" ")) {
                        counterOfWords++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfWords "+counterOfWords);
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Но что-то не видно что-бы они работали параллельно. Скотлько бы я не запускал программу, сколько бы не менял местами последовательность вызовов методов `calcSpaces()`, и `calcWords()`, они всегда идут по порядку вызовов в `main`. Объясните в чем моя ошибка.

Вывод консоли:

```
counterOfSpaces 1
counterOfSpaces 2
counterOfSpaces 3
counterOfSpaces 4
counterOfSpaces 5
counterOfSpaces 6
counterOfSpaces 7
counterOfSpaces 8
counterOfSpaces 9
counterOfWords 1
counterOfWords 2
counterOfWords 3
counterOfWords 4
counterOfWords 5
counterOfWords 6
counterOfWords 7
counterOfWords 8
counterOfWords 9
counterOfWords 10
```

Comment: Возьмите страницу текста и `System.out.println(counterOfWords);` вставьте в ваш цикл `for` а не в конец. И сразу все увидите

Comment: как вы определяете, что "они всегда идут по порядку вызовов в main"? чтобы увидеть параллельность, вам надо запихнуть внутрь циклов for вывод System.out.println("I'm calcSpaces!");/System.out.println("I'm calcWords!");

Comment: Ещё больше строк, страницу возьмите.

Comment: На самом деле это ошибка пренебрежения масштабами. Нам всегда кажется, что компьютер быстрее нас, но не на много, раз в 100, например. На то, на сколько мы можем себе представить. А он еще быстрее. На много быстрее. В миллионы раз быстрее. И что бы заметить разницу в скорости выполнения программы, мы должны приблизиться к порогу скорости компьютера, а не ориентироваться на свою. Загрузи поток перебором всех long в Long хотя бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И текста возьмите НЕ 2 слова!

```
void calcSpaces() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (text.length() == 0) return;
            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                if (c == ' ') {
                    counterOfSpaces++;
                }
                System.out.println("counterOfSpaces "+counterOfSpaces);
            }


        }
    }).start();
}

void calcWords() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (text.length() == 0) return;
            String[] words = text.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (!word.equals(" ")) {
                    counterOfWords++;
                }
                System.out.println("counterOfWords "+counterOfWords);
            }


        }
    }).start();
}
```